# Sync postgres database table between 2 webservices

Tags: database, postgresql, web-services, architecture, restful-architecture

We have a Django app (REST webservice1) and a postGres database (db1) backing it up.

We also have another REST webservice2 and its own db2.

There is a table1 in db1. Lets say that is original point of truth (original copy). table1 create/update/delete calls come to webservice1. Whenever these actions happen in webservice1, it modifies the data in table1 and also emits events (into AWS kinesis. Push to kinesis is retried but might fail) like

- item_created
- item_deleted
- item_modified

We want to migrate the data of table1 from db1 to db2 (and also keep them in sync as much as possible). webservice2 should not expose any stale data related to table1 from its endpoint. webservice2 has the option to query webservice1 for table1 data, but the whole idea is to reduce the load of db queries on webservice1.

I was wondering whats the best/easiest way to keep the contents of table1 almost at parity in webservice2.

- Any postgres specific technique we can use? like an exe which keeps track of changelog in table1 and keep pushing the data to webservice2?
- webservice2 can listen to events and query the particular data from webservice1 and save it in its db. The problem arises if those stream events are lost.

Suggestions are invited.

Comment: You can probably use [Bucardo](https://bucardo.org/wiki/Bucardo/Documentation/Overview) for single-table replication between your two databases.

Comment: Is your webservice 2 only goong to query the data from synced table?

Comment: yes, for now we just want webservice2 to expose the data of table1. Later in future we might need smth more.

Answer (score 0):

Look at a hot-standby server to do master/slave replication, it's pretty much designed for this use-case https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/high-availability.html